# termux infrared transmit the IR port does not work

Tags: termux-linux

I enter a command in Termux to control the ir, but the ir does not light up, I tried other numbers that I found
`termux-infrared-transmit -f 20, 50`

termux-infrared-transmit -f 38028 1578,1026,579,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,10860,1026,579,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,10860,1026,579,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,10860,1026,579,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,10860,1026,579,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,579,605,1446,605,1446,605,104712

I expected that the IR would at least light up